# Do all React (or Flux/React) applications must have some top App component?

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux

I have a small app that uses React. I have only two React components in it: a `MessageBox` and a `SearchBox`. The `MessageBox` renders a list of messages and the `SearchBox` only renders an `<input type="text" placeholder="Say something">` element with no functionality, like onClick or smth. Thay are as simple as can only be.

Here is the `MessageBox` component:

```
var MessageBox = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            data: []
        }
    },
    componentWillMount: function() { },
    componentDidMount: function() {
        this.setState({
            data: this.props.data
        });
    },
    componentWillUnmount: function(a, b) { },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <MessagList data={this.state.data} />
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var MessagList = React.createClass({
    componentWillMount: function () { },
    componentDidMount: function() { },
    componentWillUnmount: function() { },
    render: function() {
        var data = this.props.data || [];
        var messages = data.map(function(item, i) {
            return <Message index={i} key={i} text={item.text} />
        })
        return (
            <ul className="msgUl">
                {messages}
            </ul>
        );
    }
});

var Message = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <li className="message">
                {this.props.text}
            </li>
        );
    }
});
```

And here is the `SearchBox` component:

```
var SearchBox = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div className="searchbox">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Say something" />
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

So, the main point here is that they are absolutely separate from DOM, in terms of that they are not children of some global React component that has all the markup and that uses my `MessageBox` and `SearchBox` as children.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <body>
        <SearchBox />
        <MessageBox data={some_data} />
```

I render my components in an arbitrary DOM element I want. They are not children of some App:

```
        ReactDOM.render(
            <MessageBox data={window.data} />, document.getElementById('message-box')
        );

        ReactDOM.render(
            <SearchBox />, document.getElementById('searchbox')
        );
```

Now I examine for example [Flux examples](https://github.com/christianalfoni/flux-react-boilerplate/blob/master/app/main.js) or [react-router](https://github.com/rackt/react-router) example. And I wonder, they all practice one top `App` component that represents whole page markup, like this:

```
// flux-react-boilerplate
var React = require('react');
var App = require('./App.js');
React.render(<App/>, document.body);  // <== append right in body

// react-router
render((
  <Router>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <Route path="about" component={About}/>
      <Route path="users" component={Users}>
        <Route path="/user/:userId" component={User}/>
      </Route>
      <Route path="*" component={NoMatch}/>
    </Route>
  </Router>
), document.body)  // <== append right in body
```

And a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bic_sFiaNDI) that React popularize also involves global App component.

My question is. Is this some kind of their "best practices" to use React? Do I have to develop my apps using React in my markup exactly from top to bottom, from `<html>` to `</html>`? Can I use Flux in my case with only two separate components?

Answer (score 2):

You are perfectly fine doing it the way you are doing. There not an inherent reason why you should always use an `App` component.

However, as you can read from [this source](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2888-experimenting-with-higher-order-components-in-reactjs.htm)...

> In ReactJS, there is this emerging concept of "Higher-Order Components." These are components that wrap around other components and provide additional behavior and data input (through properties).

Some times it makes sense to wrap all (or most of) your components into a single top most component, especially so that the components beneath it will be pure. That is, the components beneath it will not be aware of the router or flux, for instance. They will receive everything they need as props. This helps keeping separation of concerns, but again, you are not required to do this.

### React router

`react-router` needs to be the top most component below which your routes will take effect. Because `react-router` is the one that will determine which component to render based on the current URL.

[Example taken from here](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/README.md)

```
render((
  <Router>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <Route path="about" component={About}/>
      <Route path="users" component={Users}>
        <Route path="/user/:userId" component={User}/>
      </Route>
    </Route>
  </Router>
), document.body)
```

### Redux

I'm taking Redux as an example of Flux implementation here because it's the most popular. In the case of Redux, it makes sense to wrap your application because it uses a `connect` function to automatically inject props on your app based on the application state. It also automatically passes in action creators.

[Example taken from here](https://github.com/rackt/react-redux/blob/master/docs/quick-start.md#quick-start)

```
// App.js
// ... imports removed for simplicity
// Which part of the Redux global state does our component want to receive as props?
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    value: state.counter
  }
}

// Which action creators does it want to receive by props?
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    onIncrement: () => dispatch(increment())
  }
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(App)
```

In the above example, `App` will receive a `value` prop containing the `counter` app state. It will also receive on `onIncrement` action creator. Even though the `App` component is agnostic, the module `App.js` knows about `Redux`, but components beneath it don't.

**TL;DR**:

You are fine not using higher-order components, but some times it makes sense.